# How to create a new object with the variable value

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have many objects for example lets say one of the object name is flipkart

```
let flipkart = function() {
  this.name = 'flipkart'
  // other functionality....
}

flipkart.prototype.someFunction = function(someValue) {
    console.log(someValue);
};
```

this is what I am trying to do I get the object names in variable lets say

```
let myVariable = 'flipkart';
```

I want to create a new object or access flipkart object which is already created.

```
const objFlipkart = Object.create(myVariable);

objFlipkart.someFunction('someValue');
```

Is there any way to get this working.

Comment: This is doable by keeping a map of objects keyed by name and either fetching or instantiating each one. Alternatively, making each object a singleton responsible for itself. However, at the same time it's a code smell - if you need that much complexity and you don't know whether they are created or not, then it seems like the code is disorganised and does too many things.

Answer (score 0):

If you look on MDN docs, you can see something about [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) where you can insert an object like:

```
const flipkart = {
    name: 'flipkart',
    someFunction: function(someValue) {
        console.log(someValue);
    }
}
```

and then make a copy of said `flipkart` by using `Object.create()`:

```
const copiedFlipkart = Object.create(flipkart);
```

where you will then have the functionality with the new (exact same, but stored in a new memory location, so any changes won't affect the original `flipkart`) you wanted:

```
copiedFlipkart.name = "A new flipcart";

copiedFlipkart.someFunction('someValue');
```